# Fetch a number of variable length from a file using pattern matching?

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, hp-ux

I have many files on UNIX and wish to fetch number in that file associated with a specified pattern.

Most of the file will have a unique pattern in file like below

```
some text abc
some text abc
some text abc
(3 rows)
```

The number could vary from file to file, it could be 35644 or any numeric value as well.

I want to find that number **using grep or sed not awk**. so far I was able to get this. I want to do this using single line unix command including redirection if applicable.

```
grep 'rows' file.txt
```

Edit - Removed the requirement if pattern is not found what should happen.

Comment: So, are you saying that your example file is four lines long, and the fourth line contains the text `(3 rows)`?  And that you want to extract the `3` from the `(3 rows)` line (regardless of the actual number of lines in the file)?  Do you guarantee that only one row in the file contains the word `row` — or that only one line will begin with `(`, followed by a sequence of digits, followed by a space and `rows)`? (If there are only two lines in the file, will the second one say `(1 row)` or `(1 rows)`?) Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: That one row will begin with `(numbercount rows)` and will have this pattern. It might possible rows might come as string somewhere else but not as this pattern `(numbercount rows)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n -e 's/^(\([0-9]\+\) rows)$/\1/p'
```

This prints the digits immediately following the `(` on lines that contain only `(nnn rows)` (where nnn is any positive integer).

No other lines are printed.

Comment: I tried this by specifying file name with pattern didn'print anything.  sed -n -e `'s/^(\([0-9]\+\) rows)$/\1/p' file.txt`

Comment: then your file doesn't match what you specified in your question.  did your files come from a windows machine? (i.e. do they have CR+LF line endings rather than unix-style LF-only?).   Try adding `\r\?` immediately before the `$` in the sed script - that will match either unix or windows line-endings.  or convert them to unix text files with `fromdos` or similar.

Comment: file is created in unix only with LF style.

Comment: then what you stated in your question is incorrect - it does not accurately describe your files.  I tested it before I posted using the sample text you provided and it printed `3`.

Comment: I'm on HP UNIX will sed command differ all versions of UNIX? As command is getting executed successfully but doesn't print anything. My requirement is clear and same as what I have posted.

Comment: That sed script uses only basic regular expressions and AFAIK, should work with HP's `sed`.  I am not an expert on HP unix.

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work in my case.

Comment: A few minutes of googling indicates that HP's version of sed may not support capture groups.  try awk or perl instead.  or install GNU sed.

Comment: FYI you can find ports of open source software to hpux 11i at http://hpux.connect.org.uk/